# View address of entry point in eax register for a suspended process in windbg

Tags: c++, windows, windbg

For a `32` bit process on `32` bit system, `EAX` register holds the address of entry point. But windbg always shows `0` for this thread.

After creating a process in suspended state and doing

```
 .thread <thread_address>
 r
```

shows

```
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=828b0c26 esp=8fe0ba04 ebp=8fe0ba48 iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na po nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0000  es=0000  fs=0000  gs=0000             efl=00000000
nt!KiSwapContext+0x26:
828b0c26 8b2c24          mov     ebp,dword ptr [esp]  ss:0010:8fe0ba04=8fe0ba48
```

On checking using `GetThreadContext()`, I get the current value in `EAX`.

```
if (!CreateProcess("test.exe", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr, nullptr, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create process " << GetLastError();
    return 1;
}

CONTEXT Ctx;
Ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
GetThreadContext(ProcessInfo.hThread, &Ctx);
std::cout << Ctx.Eax << "\n"; //ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint
```

Why does `windbg` show `0` instead of the address of entry point.

Comment: Why do you think EAX holds the address of the entry point?

Comment: You should check the `GetThreadContext()` return value

Comment: on your image at all **kernel mode** context - how this is related to user mode thread context ?

Comment: @RbMm since I switch to the thread using `.thread`, shouldn't I be able to see the register contents?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, most of the times the entry point is in eax for 32 bit and rcx for 64 bit. And in this scenario it is definitely in eax since GetThreadContext() does give out the right value which should be imagebase+addressofentrypoint offset.

Comment: are you understand different between user and kernel mode context ?

Comment: @RbMm clearly his code is usermode. Why are you asking if it's kernel?

Comment: @Nina - how his code is related ? are you not view that he look kernel mode context in windbg ? (*eip=828b0c26 esp=8fe0ba04* etc) so he look for at all unrelated between self things. and i not asking *if it kernel*. i say that here kernel mode context from windbg. OP at all bad understand what is thread context if confusing such things

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - **user mode** context of new created thread (if it created via *CreateThread* but not with more low level api) really (current implementation) store address of user defined entry point (not initial entry point) in *eax*. but in *windbg* op not look for thread **user mode** context.he view it **kernel mode** context, which is absolute unrelated. so if you look at different things - do not be surprised that we see different results

Comment: @RbMm I realize that i was viewing the kernel context. I attached a local debugger to the suspended process and could then see the expected value in `EAX`. Is there a way to switch to user mode thread context from kernel debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have created a suspended process like below in your target (vm / physical machine)
and You are connected to that machine  using a kernel debugger
and you have proper private pdbs for the   binary  you can simply ask windbg to give you the Context.Eax using ?? c++ expression Evaluator

code for test

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
    printf("lets Create a suspended process and look at it in kd\n");
    STARTUPINFO si ={0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi ={0};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    char *cmdln = "c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe\0";
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,cmdln,NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi ))
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%x).\n", GetLastError() );
        return 0;
    }
    CONTEXT ctx ={0};
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &ctx);
    printf("Eax = %x\n",ctx.Eax);

    int ans = 'n';
    while (ans != 'y') 
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        ans = getchar();        
    }
    printf("resuming the process\n");
    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);    
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    printf("wait returned closing handles\n");
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

compiled an linked with

```
cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /EHsc cpsusp.cpp /link /release
```

copied the compiled executable to a vm running 32bit win7sp1 and double clicked it 
it executed printed the eax and is waiting for a keypress

[image]

and in the kd that is connected to this vm  you can find this actual value of eax

```
kd> !process 0 2 cpsusp.exe  <<< find the DirectoryBase and Threads of Process one is interested in 

PROCESS 841cad40  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0110    Peb: 7ffd5000  ParentCid: 008c
    DirBase: 0f90a000  ObjectTable: 95d5d210  HandleCount:  12.
    Image: cpsusp.exe

        THREAD 841b8d48  Cid 0110.0644  Teb: 7ffdf000 Win32Thread: 00000000 WAIT:
 (WrLpcReply) UserMode Non-Alertable
            841b8f7c  Semaphore Limit 0x1

kd> .thread /p /r /P 841b8d48    << setting the thread context (just .thread isn't enough
Implicit thread is now 841b8d48    Implicit process is now 841cad40
.cache forcedecodeptes done
kd> kb
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 8ce3bae8 8285bd75 841b8d48 82925f08 82922d20 nt!KiSwapContext+0x26
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX snipped off irrelevent stack 
16 0015f8e0 013d13d4 00000001 002cfe60 002d0bd8 cpsusp!main+0x114 [e:\code\cpsusp\cpsusp.cpp @ 25] 
YYYYYYYYYYYYY  snipped of iirelevent stack 
1b 0015f98c 00000000 013d14b9 7ffd5000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

kd> .frame /r /c 0x16   <<<< seeting the frame and forcing to retrieve the actual volatile registers
16 0015f8e0 013d13d4 cpsusp!main+0x114 [e:\code\cpsusp\cpsusp.cpp @ 25]
cpsusp!main+0x114:
001b:013d1114 89852cfdffff    mov     dword ptr [ebp-2D4h],eax
kd> dv
            ctx = struct _CONTEXT   <<<<<<<<<
          cmdln = 0x014101d8 "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"
             pi = struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION
            ans = 0n110
             si = struct _STARTUPINFOA
kd> ?? ctx.Eax  <<<<<<
unsigned long 0x212d6c   <<<< this is the value you got printed in the remote machine
```